# Cover background-size on mobile

Tags: html, css, background, responsive

I have a problem with my website. The picture looks great on the desktop but on my phone it looks terrible because its zoomed in.

How can I solve this?
It don´t work with

```
background-size:cover;
```

The div with the background have two classes

```
.content{
    color: white; 
    font-family: "Another Typewriter"; 
    width:100%; height:1000px;  
    font-size: 300%; 
    padding-left: 15%; 
    padding-right: 15%; 
    padding-top: 10%; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-size: cover;
}

.parallax{
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
}
#xyz{background-image: url(URLtoimage);}
```

Div Container:

```
    <div id="xyz" class="parallax content">
    <legend class="text-center content-headline">XYZ</legend>
Some text
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have more code like HTML and CSS you are using???

Comment: Did you include the [viewport meta tag](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)? ex: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I've assumed you're using `background-attachment: fixed;` , it can't work on many mobile browser you must use media query to change it on scroll for little screen.

```
.parallax{
   height: 100%; 
   background-attachment: fixed; 
   background-position: center; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-size: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not working. I edit my post and added the classes that the div have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change it to background-size: contain when the screen width is smaller than 767px

Comment: use the @media to display different images and the smaller screen width

Answer (score 0):

use background-size:100% 100%; Check the snippet view.

```css
body{
margin:0;
}
.bg-img {
  background: url('http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6942095-abstract-background-wallpaper.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">

</div>
```

Comment: well then you have some other problem. If possible add the html part and the background image. because your content and parallax class dont have any background source.

Comment: Ok i added the html